# How to see all executing codes or includes of a CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system

Suppose I have wordpress installed in my server (shared hosting) and let's say my website address is www.mydomain.com. Now when I begin to see www.mydomain.com, normally, at first it begins to execute from index.php.

Now when I open the index.php by any php editor, I can see several includes/requires such as:

```
include("wp-function.php"):
```

That wp-function.php has several other includes like:

```
include("wp-functions.php");
require_once("wp-admin.php");
```

I can manually see all the includes/requires by going to that specific included directory/file. But that requires several opening of directory/php files in tabs which actually lose to view sequential executing codes.

Is there any program or software which can show me all executing includes (page or codes) one by one in one page. There might be collapse button which will collapse the includes and will show the content php codes by expanding it.

What I want actually, to see all the executing codes needed for executing a CMS (like wordpress) page sequentially including the php file name. Is there any such software/program?

Comment: You can use xdebug and have a look at the [backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php).

Comment: As said, that kind of tool is called debugger. For PHP, Xdebug is basically the only option. You need to use it from a client program such as PhpStorm, Visual Studio Code, NetBeans... **But**... that isn't something you can normally do in live servers, let alone shared hosting plans. You'll have to execute your code locally.